Creating nested lists from a single list
Suppose I have a list like this:
my_list = ['a_norm', 'a_std', 'a_min', 'a_max', 'a_flag', 'b_norm', 'b_std', 'b_min', 'b_max', 'b_flag', 'c_norm', 'c_std', 'c_min', 'c_max', 'c_flag']

I want to parse this list and create nested lists within separate lists like this. It is very important that I retain the order of the :
a_list = [[1, "a_norm"], [2, "a_std"], [3, "a_min"], [4, "a_max"], [5, "a_flag"]]
b_list = [[1, "b_norm"], [2, "b_std"], [3, "b_min"], [4, "b_max"], [5, "b_flag"]]
c_list = [[1, "c_norm"], [2, "c_std"], [3, "c_min"], [4, "c_max"], [5, "c_flag"]]

I tried the below which, in addition to being convoluted, did not work (endless loop). Any suggestions on how to accomplish my end goal?
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
while (i < 6) and (j < 6) and (k < 6):
    for item in my_list:
        if 'a' in item:
            a_list.append(i)
            a_list.append(item)
            i + 1
        elif 'b' in my_list:
            b_list.append(j)
            b_list.append(item)
            j + 1
        elif 'c' in my_list:
            c_list.append(k)
            c_list.append(item)
            k + 1


depend on what you order the values like (a_norm , a_std) , why a_std is not 1 for example ?

@Mohammedalmalki - The order must remain fixed. Assume that the order should match the desired outcome for this question.

"retain the order of the"...?

Desired outcome. Essentially: order = {"norm":1, "std":2,"min":3,"max":4,"flag":5}

Stack Overflow is meant for specific questions, so "suggestions" is too broad. What exactly do you need help with? Like to start, do you realize that the while loop is unnecessary, set is not what you want, and i + 1 has no effect? Check out [ask] and you can [edit] to clarify if needed.

Apologies - I updated the code in the question. I assumed that while would work and that updating the counters (i, j, k) would also work to assign the value in the nested list until it reached 5. Obviously it did not, which is why I posted the question. Did you really have to deduct a point?

This will do the parsing you want; you can then assign the items in parsed_lists as you wish.
parsed_lists = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[]}
for x in my_list:
    v = parsed_lists[x[0]]
    v.append([len(v)+1,x])

which results in:
{'a': [[1, 'a_norm'], [2, 'a_std'], [3, 'a_min'], [4, 'a_max'], [5, 'a_flag']], 
 'b': [[1, 'b_norm'], [2, 'b_std'], [3, 'b_min'], [4, 'b_max'], [5, 'b_flag']], 
 'c': [[1, 'c_norm'], [2, 'c_std'], [3, 'c_min'], [4, 'c_max'], [5, 'c_flag']]}


Great answer. I went with this because it was the most succinct. Appreciate all the answers and feedback.

You can use itertools.groupby to group your original list into subsequences based on the first letter of each list element.
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> f = itemgetter(0)
>>> my_list = ['a_norm', 'a_std', 'a_min', 'a_max', 'a_flag', 'b_norm', 'b_std', 'b_min', 'b_max', 'b_flag', 'c_norm', 'c_std', 'c_min', 'c_max', 'c_flag']
>>> d = {k: list(map(list, enumerate(v, start=1))) for k, v in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=f), f)}
>>> d['a']
[[1, 'a_norm'], [2, 'a_std'], [3, 'a_min'], [4, 'a_max'], [5, 'a_flag']]


this code does your jobs that you want,
but I do not know depends on what you order the values like (a_norm , a_std) , why a_std is not 1 for example ?
but this is the code:
my_list = ['a_norm', 'a_std', 'a_min', 'a_max', 'a_flag', 'b_norm', 'b_std', 'b_min', 'b_max', 'b_flag', 'c_norm', 'c_std', 'c_min', 'c_max', 'c_flag']

letters = {}

order = {"norm":1,
         "std":2,
         "min":3,
         "max":4,
         "flag":5}

for i in my_list:
    letter = i.split("_")[0]
    value = i.split("_")[1]

    to_append = [order.get(value), i]

    if letters.get(letter):
        letters.get(letter).append(to_append)
    else:
        letters.update({letter : [to_append]})

print(letters)

a_list = letters.get("a")
b_list = letters.get("b")
c_list = letters.get("c")

print(a_list)
print(b_list)
print(c_list)

